# .htaccess grab whole path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

i'm experimenting with a method for pretty urls i haven't tried before where htaccess just grans the whole path after the root and passes it as a single variable, then i will break it up into specific variables using php explode, but i'm getting stuck early on.

I'm using this line to grab everything in the url after "blah.com" -

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

then in php use this line to turn it into a variable

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

but when i test it with a fake path, like "blah.com/test/test2" $url echos as "index.php" instead of "test/test2"

i hate working with htaccess, which is one of the reasons im trying this method, so i'm not sure what i need to do to fix this. any help would be... very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with GET variables, just inspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, infinitely simpler :)

Comment: so something like....

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php [NC]

and

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

?

Comment: Indeed, that's the idea. Might want to throw a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before the rule though, to prevent is redirecting when a file exist.